# Check where is located flash file sending request to PHP

Tags: php, flash, superglobals

I have a flash file that is located on my website and I have a PHP file which gets requests from flash file every 5 minutes. I want to be sure that flash file which is sending request is located on my website and not somewhere else. How can I do it. Is there anything in PHP's global variables that can help me or there is something else I can do?

Comment: Checking this from flash is no different than checking the same thing in an AJAX handler: Check referers (unreliable), use tokens (more reliable, but still not fool proof), require a validated login (better still), etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
var url:String=stage.loaderInfo.url;
var goodPattern:RegExp=/^(http:\/\/)(www\.)?stackoverflow\.com/;
if (goodPattern.test(url)==true) {
    trace("This flash is hosted on stackoverflow");
} else {
    trace("This flash is hosted not on stackoverflow");
}
```

Comment: Thanks but It is not reliable solution because it is on user side. I need to check it in php not in flash.

Comment: You can add data from stage.loaderInfo.url into your requests coming from flash, like a signature, or a hash of this, then compare it with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You might get something from `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` or `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']` but this information can be spoofed.

There are many methods that can be used to ensure requests are coming from a particular/legitimate source. The technique that initially comes to my mind for sender verification is using a [digital signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature). If you want to avoid using a public-private key pair, and since the request is coming from the same server that is receiving, then using a [pre-shared secret key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-shared_key) might be appropriate (just be sure to hash with a salt).